# Doubt regarding zero elements in factor ring :$\mathbb Z[i]/\langle3-i\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have the factor ring $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle3-i\rangle$ and am asked to find elements zero in this ,they are $0,3-i,i(3-i),(3-i)+i(3-i)$.

But I can't understand how do we guarantee these are the only zero elements and there are no more.....

Please help I'm STRUCK.......

Comment: You want "zero elements" or **zero divisors** , @cool ?

Comment: @Timbuc zero elements .....

Comment: Well, that's odd @cool :as user's answer mentions, in **any** ring there is one, unique zero element, which in this quotient ring case is represented by the ideal $\;I:=\langle 3-1\rangle\;$, and the elements of this ideal are of the form $\;(3-i)x\;,\;\;x\in \Bbb Z[i]\;$, as written there.

Comment: @timbuc I mean by zero elements here is that : the ways of writing a zero elemnt in the ideal .....

Comment: @coool, that's what the answer and my comment above explain.

Comment: But do not call them "zero elements": there is **only** one single zero element in *any* ring, @coool .

Comment: @Timbuc alright but then after that please see my doubt :how do we guratee by multiplying the $(3-i)$ by generators of $\Bbb Z[i]\;$ that we'll get all elemnts...please explain why only these are the elments $0,3-i,i(3-i),(3-i)+i(3-i)$

Comment: @Timbuc i HAVE the doubt how did we write $\;(3-i)x\;,\;\;x\in \Bbb Z[i]\;$ as all elemnts...please I can't get it..

Comment: @coool, please **do read** the answer below! An element belongs to a principal ideal iff it is a multiple (from the ring) of the element generating that ideal, thus in this case there are **infinite** elements that *represent* the zero element in this quotient ring: $$0=0\cdot(3-i)\;,\;\;3-i=1\cdot (3-i)\;,\;\;(3-i)+i(3-i)=(3-i)(1+i)\;,\;\;etc.$$

Comment: @Timbuc thanks for explanation....

Comment: @Timbuc I think your statement :'there are infinite elements that represent the zero element in this quotient ring' is not correct..It seem to be contrary to the no. of elemnts which can be represented as zero in question :$0,3-i,i(3-i),(3-i)+i(3-i)$  ,these are finite in no. maybe I'm wrong somwhere...

Comment: @spectraa, for *any* $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , the element $\;n(3-i)\;$ is zero in that quotient ring...What the OP **actually** meant in his question is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero element (*which is always unique*) of the quotient ring $R/I$ is the ideal $I$. In present question, $I$ consists of all elements $(3-i)x$ with $x\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Timbuc I don't see any mention of zero divisors in the question.

Comment: As odd as the question is, this answer addresses and explains what the OP asked. +1